# XML Field - Query

Tags: xml, sql-server-2008, xml-serialization

I'm not able to build a correct syntaxt in order to execute any query on my sql sever 2008 related to XML fields.

I've a simple table with fields such as Idproduct, ProductName and XmlProduct.
..And XmlProduct field looks like following:

```
<DynamicProfile xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WinTest">
  <AllData xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MyFirstValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
  </AllData>
</DynamicProfile>
```

For instance, I need to write a query which extract all rows containing  node value to "MySecondKey".
How can achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the ans with xquery operators-->

```
declare @xmldata xml
    set @xmldata = 
    '<DynamicProfile xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WinTest">
  <AllData xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MyFirstValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  </AllData>
</DynamicProfile>'

;WITH XMLNAMESPACES 
(
    DEFAULT 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WinTest',
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' as d2p1
)
SELECT  x.c.value('(d2p1:Key)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as key3, x.c.value('(d2p1:Value)[1]', 'varchar(100)') as value
FROM @xmldata.nodes('/DynamicProfile/AllData/d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring') x(c) where x.c.value('(d2p1:Key)[1]', 'varchar(100)') = 'MySecondKey'
```

Comment: Well, but in my case the @xmldata variable is a table field. So, consider you want execute a query to extract all rows which match with xml where clausole, how can I do it?

Comment: check this article-- > http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3674311/Query-XML-data-from-a-table-with-XML-data-type.htm

Comment: Nothing to do. For me it's not important "translate" the xml field, instead I would only retrieve all rows affected by my where condition. Where condifition refers to xml field, but finally all what i want to achieve are "native" rows, for example: Select * from MyTable WHERE XmlField.Value(key) = 'some value'

Comment: Ok, solved..The following is just what I want: WITH XMLNAMESPACES  
( 
    'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' as d2p1 
) 
select * from MyTable where
MyXmlField.exist('//d2p1:Key[.="MyFirstKey"]') = 1

Answer (score 0):

You can use following TSQL code-->

```
declare @xmldata xml
    set @xmldata = 
    '<DynamicProfile xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/WinTest">
  <AllData xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MyFirstValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
    <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MySecondKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  <d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>
      <d2p1:Key>MyFirstKey</d2p1:Key>
      <d2p1:Value>MySecondValue</d2p1:Value>
    </d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring>  </AllData>
</DynamicProfile>'

 DECLARE @hDoc int, @rootxmlns varchar(100)
 SET @rootxmlns = '<AllData xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />'

 EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @xmldata, @rootxmlns  

 SELECT *
 FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, '//d2p1:KeyValueOfstringstring',2)
 WITH ([d2p1:Key] varchar(100) , [d2p1:Value] varchar(100)) where [d2p1:Key] = 'MySecondKey'

 --clean up 
 EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
```

Comment: Why do I need to declare @xmldata variable? That already exist in my table xml field. Also, is there any solution using XQuery? Something like query, value, exist methods..?

Comment: similar solution with xquery recommended here --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440848/openxml-with-xmlnsdt

Comment: Please can you post me an explicit example related to my issue?