# Parse xml in SQL server using Openxml

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, openxml

Please let me know why my query doesn't work.
Following is my XML.
Trying to parse it in SQL Server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soap:Body>
<PostEDIDataToEIP xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
<xmlRequestDetails>
<Applicant>
<ApplyData>
<RefNo>86</RefNo>
<ProfileSnapshot>
<Name>King</Name>
<ResumeHeadline>RESUME HEADLINE.......................</ResumeHeadline>
</ProfileSnapshot>
</ApplyData>
</Applicant>
</xmlRequestDetails>
</PostEDIDataToEIP>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>

set @xmlRequestDetails='Above xml'
set @xPath='/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/PostEDIDataToEIP/xmlRequestDetails/Applicant/ApplyData' 
Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @XML_Hndl OUTPUT, @xmlRequestDetails
select * into #jobdetails FROM OPENXML(@XML_Hndl,@xPath,2) with (RefNo smallint)
select * from #jobdetails 

set @xPath='/soap:Envelope/soap:Body/PostEDIDataToEIP/xmlRequestDetails/Applicant/ApplyData/ProfileSnapshot' 
select * into #personaldetails FROM OPENXML(@XML_Hndl,@xPath,2) with (Name varchar(100), ResumeHeadline varchar(100))
select * from #personaldetails
```

Receiving the following error.

```
Msg 6603, Level 16, State 2, Procedure sp_forintegration, Line 31
XML parsing error: Reference to undeclared namespace prefix: 'soap'.
The statement has been terminated.
Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Procedure sp_forintegration, Line 33
Invalid object name '#jobdetails'.
```

This xml is getting inserted into Sql server table XML column.
I feel i am doing some mistake while parsing, please let me know what can be done, or how to parse.

Thanks/Regards,
Prasanth Kumar

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare the namespace prefixes when you prepare the XML document, something along the following:

```
SET @rootxmlns = '<root xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"/>'
Exec sp_xml_preparedocument @XML_Hndl OUTPUT, @xmlRequestDetails, @rootxmlns
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1440848/openxml-with-xmlnsdt) for a more detailed example.